# VBA isEmpty() - Check if cells are empty and tell me which ones

Tags: excel, vba

Apologies if this has been answered already, I did search and can't seem to find an answer:

How could I change the code below to check for empty cells across two sheets and not in a continuous range and to tell me which cells are blank.

The range will be sheet "Request" Range, B5,B6,B7,b10,b11 & sheet "Data" Range A8, B8, D8,

Is it possible for the code to tell me the adjacent Cell name so can find it and put a value in,  for example B5, A5 is called "request name" so I'd need to highlight to the user request name is blank for them to go and put a value and so on for the other cells.

```
Sub check_empty()

Dim i As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim myRange As Range
Dim myCell As Range

Set myRange = Sheets("Request").Range("B5:B8")

For Each myCell In myRange
    c = c + 1   
    If IsEmpty(myCell) Then
        i = i + 1
    End If   
Next myCell   

MsgBox _
"There are total " & i & " empty cell(s) out of " & c & "."

End Sub
```

Comment: What are the 'adjacent' cells on the sheet 'Data'?

Comment: Have you tried the answer below?...

Answer (score 0):

Is it correct the range for sheet "Data"?
Cause Range A8 won't have a named range adjacent to it, and B8 would have A8 as its named range... anyway, here's what I came up with:

```
Sub check_empty()

    Dim c As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sReport As String
    Dim rResults() As String

    c = 0
    i = 0
    Call loop_check_empty("Request", "B5:B7,B10:B11", rResults, c, i)
    Call loop_check_empty("Data", "A8,B8,D8", rResults, c, i)

    sReport = Join(rResults, vbCr)
    MsgBox "There are total " & i & " empty cell(s) out of " & c & "." & vbCr & sReport

End Sub

Sub loop_check_empty(ByVal sSheet As String, ByVal sRange As String, ByRef rResults() As String, ByRef c As Integer, ByRef i As Integer)

    Dim myCell, myRange As Range
    Dim sColumn, sRow As String

    Set myRange = Sheets(sSheet).Range(sRange)

    For Each myCell In myRange
        c = c + 1
        If IsEmpty(myCell) Then
            i = i + 1
            ReDim Preserve rResults(1 To i)
            sColumn = Mid(myCell.Address, 2, 1)
            sRow = Mid(myCell.Address, 4, Len(myCell.Address))
            Sheets(sSheet).Range(sColumn & sRow).Interior.Color = vbRed
            If sColumn = "A" Then
                rResults(i) = sColumn & sRow
            Else
                rResults(i) = sColumn & sRow & " for "
                sColumn = Chr(Asc(sColumn) - 1)
                rResults(i) = rResults(i) & Sheets(sSheet).Range(sColumn & sRow).Name.Name
            End If
        End If
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

Assuming the ranges A5, A6, A7, A10 and A11, in sheet "Request" are named ranges.
And ranges A8 and C8 in sheet "Data".
The code will turn sheet "Request" Range, B5,B6,B7,b10,b11 & sheet "Data" Range A8, B8, D8 all into red, so the user will know where to enter data.
And the msgbox will report the empty ranges, as well as the named range adjacent to it.